# How to close a window programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Please tell me why the function `quit()` does not close the program. I use python3.3

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
class Quitter(tkinter.Frame):                          
    def __init__(self, parent=None):          
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        widget = tkinter.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        widget.pack(side='left', expand='yes', fill=tkinter.BOTH)
    def quit(self):
        ans = tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel('Verify exit', "Really quit?")
        if ans:
            print('exitt')
            tkinter.Frame.quit(self)
        else:
            print('noexitt')
if __name__ == '__main__':  Quitter().mainloop()
```

Comment: Running this in Python 3.3, it works for me.  The window closes, and the process exits.

Comment: sorry. it works in command line running. but among IDLE it not works

Comment: Try using `self.master.destroy()` instead of `tkinter.Frame.quit()` to kill the application.  The latter only quits the frame.  The former will cause the root application to stop.